# How to buid wordpress menu with auto width sub-menu items in dropdown menu without any items sharing one line

Tags: menus, css, html, navigation, sub-menu

How do I buid wordpress menu with auto width sub-menu items in dropdown menu without any sub-menu items sharing one line (appearing side by side).but with an automatic width for dropdown items that is without setting a pre defined width. I tried This Code

```
<html>
    <header>
<ul> 
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">About</a> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">History</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Offices</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </li> 
  <li><a href="#">Services</a> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Internet 
            Marketing</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Domain Names</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">France</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">USA</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">longwordtestsubjecT</a></li>  
      </ul> 
    </li> 
  </ul>
    </header>
  <style>
      
      li{
    display: inline-block !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0 38px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
      }
      
 ul li {
     float:left; 
     position:relative; 
     text-transform:uppercase; 
     list-style:none
      }
 ul li a {
     display:block;  
     color:#000; 
     padding:5px 15px; 
     font-size:14px;
     color: #808080;
     text-decoration: none;
      }

/* Second Level */
 ul li ul 
      {
     display:none;
      }
 ul li ul li a 
      {
       width:auto;
       display:block;
      }
 ul li:hover ul {
     display:block; 
     position:absolute; 
     top:26px;
      }

/* Third Level */
 ul li ul li ul li
      {
     list-style:inside square
      }
 ul li ul li ul li a 
      {font-size:11px; 
      color:#ddd}
</style>
  </html>
```

And this is what i get ! Sub-menu Item Appearing side by side instead of on their own line...
[image]

I would like it to look like this but still maintain the automatic width
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining a certain width to each item from the second list, you could use the following to modify the styling for the submenu:

```
ul li ul li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It will look like this:
[image]

You could also try using CSS Grid or CSS Flex to accomplish the structure.